# Advanced Laravel Search Functionality Using Scout

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout

I have a Model named **Profile** in my project and i want to search user's full name through the records using *Laravel Scout*.

**Search Function**

```
public function SearchUser(Request $request)
{
    $searchProfileQuery = Profile::search($request->input('query'))->get();
    
    return view('users/search-result', compact('searchProfileQuery'));
}
```

Let's say there are 2 records :

- Ben Hubble
- Dean Russel

Current Condition :

- If i search using 'e' keyword, both records are shown
- If i search using 'dean' or 'Dean', only Dean Russel will be shown

**QUESTION :**

- How if i misspelled the keyword 'Dean' with 'Dena' but Dean Russel still shown?
- Or how if i make the keyword with excessive vowels like 'Been' but Ben Hubble still shown?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the database engine as laravel scout driver, the comparison is done by executing a SQL LIKE query against the desired fields as described here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scout#database-engine

What you'd like to have is an additional feature that is not part of the database engine. If switching to another engine like algolia is possible, please have a look at the Algolia typo tolerance documentation: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/typoTolerance/